# Install Ubuntu 14.04 abort due to weired mouse move with ASUS R409C

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, touchpad, asus

When I try to install Ubuntu 14.04, on an ASUS R409C, the touchpad works fine until the language selection step. Then the cursor periodically moves to left (about 1cm at once) up to the edge of the screen and then freezes. During this weired cursor move, the touchpad does not respond to my commands. Then, without touchpad, it is impossible to complete the install process.

Image ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso.

Video card NVIDIA GEFORCE GT720M.

ASUS Touchpad plugged into [built-in] PS/2 mouse port.

Same issue occurs with ASUS X550.

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried using another mouse? After installation it will be easier to change settings/install drivers for your touchpad.

Answer (score 0):

**The only solution right now is to use an external mouse.**

This problem with the touchpad affects several users of Asus X550CA / X550LC / X450L / X450CC and probably other models.

You can subscribe to this [bug on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1314198) in order to be notified when something new concerning this issue is posted, and maybe provide information in order to help debug this issue.

Comment: I've made a blog post to summarize everything I know on this subject: [Asus touchpad not detected under Ubuntu Linux](http://cksum.blogspot.com/2014/06/asus-touchpad-not-detected-under-ubuntu.html). This bug affects at least Asus X450CC, X550CA, X550LB, X550LC, X550LD, X750LB